# Bug in displaying panel data (Grafana dashboard)

Tags: grafana, trino, grafana-plugin

I use Trino as a data source in Grafana 9, I have a dashboard that includes a number of panels with “time series” visualization. When I open the dashboard, the data of each panel is randomly displayed in strange ways, and I need to put the panel in view mode and refresh it several times so that the correct graph is finally displayed. Do you think this is not a bug on Grafana’s side? Because if the data is wrong, it should not be corrected even by refreshing the panel.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjKpY.png)

Comment: Use inspect context menu of your panels to check data used for graphs when they are showing expected and unexpected graphs. Also, investigate your queries, it's possible you have some issue with time aggregation, or ranging. And finally check if all your queries have proper ordering: AFAIK it's recommended but not required, but theoretically I believe it might have some impact.

Comment: I checked the data through the "inspect context menu" in both expected and unexpected graphs and the data were similar.

Comment: SELECT 
DATE_KEY, 
kimchi,
pizza
FROM ****
WHERE DATE_KEY between ${__from:date:YYYYMMDD} and ${__to:date:YYYYMMDD}
GROUP BY DATE_KEY

Comment: The date-key column type is numeric and I used "Transform/Convert Field Type" to use the "Time Series" mode and first converted the date-key to string and then to time, Also I used a special "where Clause" that I can dynamically apply the time range in the query.

The date-key column type is numeric and I used "Transform/Convert Field Type" to use the "Time Series" mode and first converted the date-key to string and then to time, Also I used a special "where Clause" that I can dynamically apply the time range in the query.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "AFAIK".

Comment: AFAIK = as far as I know. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: If you are using time series mode, I believe you must provide data ordered by date. Have you tried adding `ORDER BY DATE_KEY`?

Comment: It was necessary to add this "ORDER BY DATE_KEY", thank you very much, you are very smart